# Swift Viewcontroller.type does not have a member named

Tags: swift

This is my code at the very top I have:

```
var newPurchase:Purchase = Purchase()
```

Then at the bottom I have :

```
class func updateLabels(label: UILabel, item: String)
{
    label.text = newPurchase.purchaseLemonsBalance  //  ViewController.type does not have a member named 'newPurchase'
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access instance variables in class functions.

If you want to access instance variables you have to turn your class function into an instance function:

change

```
class func updateLabels(label: UILabel, item: String)
```

to

```
func updateLabels(label: UILabel, item: String)
```